# MUI Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `#ff9800` supplied to `ForwardRef(Link)`,

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I set the color to `white` and `ff9800` like below.
And am getting this error message.

```sh
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `#ff9800` supplied to `ForwardRef(Link)`, expected one of ["initial","inherit","primary","secondary","textPrimary","textSecondary","error"].
```

How can I get rid of this?

```js
 <Typography variant='body2' color='white' align='center'>
    {'Copyright  '}
    <Link color='#ff9800' target='_blank' href=''></Link>
    {' '}
    {new Date().getFullYear()}
    {'.'}
 </Typography>
```

Comment: Simply change the `color='#ff9800'` within `<Link>` component to something like `color="primary"` (as you can see the provided options in the error message...

Comment: I am trying to set the color to #ff9800. Not the primary or secondary color.

Comment: Yes, so then you'd need to `override` the primary color, or whatever other color already set. The provided answer also works if just setting it up for one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it as inline style props: `style={{ color: '#ff9800' }}`

So your code becomes:

```
 <Typography variant='body2' style={{ color: '#ff9800' }} align='center'>
    {'Copyright  '}
    <Link style={{ color: '#ff9800' }} target='_blank' href=''></Link>
    {' '}
    {new Date().getFullYear()}
    {'.'}
 </Typography>
```

Just apply to any one `<Component/>`, preferably inner component, it will work.